# How to show streams inline as HTTP chunked response with play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Am following the "[Streaming HTTP Response](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaStream)" documentation of Play2! framework which describes how a file or stream could be sent as chunked responses. The http-action code I wrote after reading this is very simple -

```
Ok.chunked(
  Enumerator.fromStream(istream).andThen(Enumerator.eof)
)
```

With this code everytime I refresh the URL the data in the stream gets downloaded as a file by the browser. Instead of downloading as a file I want the stream content to shown *inline* in the browser as text. The File example on the documentation page describes how one could do this with files... but looking at the APIs I dont see an *inline* option with streams. So is it possible to show stream data inline with chunked responses everytime I refresh the browser? If my expectation is invalid then a little explanation of why-so will be very welcome.

Comment: Have you tried setting a `content-type` supported by your browser (like text/plain or text/xml) when sending the response?

Comment: Yes, that does it! Thank you! The code that worked was -
`Ok.chunked(
  Enumerator.fromStream(istream).andThen(Enumerator.eof)
).as("text/html")`

Now how can I mark your comment as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my comment: You should set a `content-type` supported by your browser (like text/plain or text/xml) when sending the response, otherwise you're just sending bytes and the browser doesn't "know" it can display it.

Update: adding the exact code that solved the issue:

```
Ok.chunked( Enumerator.fromStream(istream).andThen(Enumerator.eof) ).as("text/html")
```